What's meaning of this saying regarding the word taraib
في قوله : يَخْرُجُ مِنْ بَين الصّلْب والتّرَائِبِ قال : الترائب : الأضلاع التي أسفل الصلب
This roughly translates in English to:(taraib "ترائب") are the ribs that are below the backbone (sulb"صلب").
What does ribs below backbones means? Did any scholars ever explained the meaning of this?
Please help me understand? Is this referring last ribs like floating ribs 11 or 12?

Actually  الصلب is the spine and الترائب is the thorax. So the location is covered or protected by these bone structures. The addition "Below" in the interpretation is to be more precise that the part of bones meant are those of the bottom.

What would say the space in between these two things. Verse is 86:7. Says emerging from between الصلب and الترائب. So is the verse saying space in between is thoracic region. And if yes as per my initial inquiry is it saying lower thoracic region or upper.

Your rough translations are incorrect because الصلب is the spine and الترائب is the thorax. So the location is covered or protected by these bone structures.
In other words, Verse (86:7) describes the location where the fluid or secretion is located which helps sperms to reach the urethra this was already referred to in verse (86:6) by:

He was created from a fluid, ejected,

From medical science or from today's knowledge we know that this secretion is produced or emerges from the Prostate.

الترائب : الأضلاع التي أسفل الصلب
at-Taraa-ib: the rib bones which are located at the bottom of the thorax.

What you have literally and wrongly interpreted as "below", is a reference for the bottom or lower part, meaning the lower bones of the thorax in the interpretation you have shared.
However, scholars disputed the correct meaning and had many other interpretations, which are at least far away from a modern scientific or anatomic description as the above interprtation may indicate. Imam a-Tabari in his Tafsir mentioned the statement you have quoted and regarded it as less correct as you may read on islamqa fatwa #118879.
Note: It must be clear that the qur'an is not a science book. So anything that can be explained technically or scientifically by our modern wisdom may not have been possible -due to lack of knowledge or scientific proof- in the early days of Islam. Therefore, it is pointless to cling to certain interpretations.
Traditional tafsir relies -besides other sources- on the following:

Arabic language and it meanings as a source of interpretation.
The reports of sahabah () who are known for their knowledge about the qur'an and it's interpretation.
Usage or explanations that are in the qur'an itself.

Neither of these can give us an expert's interpretation in anatomy. Further, sorry for repeating myself, early scholars regarded this -from today's persepctive- widely anatomically correct interpretation as the less correct, because of the above.

Okay maybe I'm slow and I'm not understanding this properly. are you saying between sulb and taraib is abdominal region as in we have the thorax above the backbone or or spine is behind the body and you have abdominal in the middle is this what the verse is referring to.

@Thahi please note Qur'an is not a science book, it is important to know that quran describes the region of the body where the secretion that transports sperms to the urethra as the region at the lower part of rib bones. Thus, we can say that Qur'an from a non-scientific (absolutely accurate) perspective identified the location of the prostate in an acceptably well-described manner, so that a layman can easily verify the validity of the information if a scientific description was available.

I am sorry and may Allah forgive me. I am not trying to argue against what's been said. Prostate is not at lower part of ribs. Lower part of ribs is upper lumbar. My understanding, verse saying chest (taraib) above and spine (sulb) on the back. And in between is abdominal region. But recent talk with a Christian, he said between backbone and ribs is thoracic region not abdominal. So my understanding doesn't fit and no scholars ever explained in that manner. So I am just trying to understand. So my question, between sulb and taraib is it talking about throcic region or the way I understood it.
